# Group dataframe rows by creating a unique ID column based on the amount of time passed between entries and variable values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rolling-computation

I'm trying to group the rows of my dataframe into "courses" when the same variables appear at regular date intervals. When there is a gap in time frequency or when one of variables change I would like to give it a new course ID.

To give an example, my data looks something like this:

```
         Date     Name   Item
1  2018-06-02    Johan  Apple
2  2018-07-05    Johan  Apple
3  2018-08-02    Johan  Apple
4  2019-04-15    Johan  Apple
5  2019-05-15    Johan  Apple
6  2019-05-30 Samantha Orange
7  2019-06-12 Samantha Orange
8  2019-06-27 Samantha Orange
9  2018-02-15     Mary  Lemon
10 2018-04-10     Mary  Lemon
11 2018-06-12     Mary  Lemon
12 2018-08-13     Mary   Lime
13 2018-08-27     Mary   Lime
14 2017-03-09   George   Kiwi
```

Each different combination of `Name` and `Item` should generate a new course ID.

However (the tricky part) if there is a *significant time gap* between two transactions where the other variables are constant, defined as: either *more than 6 months* **or** *more than three times the average interval up to that date* for that specific combination of `Item` and `Name` then it should be given a new `CourseID`

In my example:

- Because Johan had a break after August 2018, transactions after that should have a new `CourseID`. Ideally the interval to check for future breaks would then be based on the average in this new group.
- Samantha is buying oranges on a biweekly basis with no siginficant gap so all her transactions will have one `CourseID`.
- Mary is buying lemons at a regular interval but then switches to buying limes at a regular interval, so these have two `CourseID`s.
- George just bought the one Kiwi, so a single `CourseID`

Code to reproduce:

```
data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2018-06-02", "2018-07-05", "2018-08-02", "2019-04-15", "2019-05-15", "2019-05-30", "2019-06-12", "2019-06-27", "2018-02-15", "2018-04-10", "2018-06-12", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-27", "2017-03-09")),
           Name = c(rep("Johan", 5), rep("Samantha", 3), rep("Mary", 5), "George"),
           Item = c(rep("Apple", 5), rep("Orange", 3), rep("Lemon", 3), rep("Lime",2), "Kiwi"))
```

I'd like to create an additional column which has a unique identifier for each course - i.e. using stringi or similar.

Ideally the output would look something like this:

```
         Date     Name   Item CourseID
1  2018-06-02    Johan  Apple      q3J
2  2018-07-05    Johan  Apple      q3J
3  2018-08-02    Johan  Apple      q3J
4  2019-04-15    Johan  Apple      f8j
5  2019-05-15    Johan  Apple      f8j
6  2019-05-30 Samantha Orange      p8U
7  2019-06-12 Samantha Orange      p8U
8  2019-06-27 Samantha Orange      p8U
9  2018-02-15     Mary  Lemon      wi9
10 2018-04-10     Mary  Lemon      wi9
11 2018-06-12     Mary  Lemon      wi9
12 2018-08-13     Mary   Lime      q8U
13 2018-08-27     Mary   Lime      q8U
14 2017-03-09   George   Kiwi      jJ0
```

I've tried going about this using max/min on the date varaible, however I'm stumped when it comes to identifying the break based on the previous purchasing pattern.

There may be a package I don't know which has something for this, however I've been trying with Tidyverse so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr approach that calculates the gap and rolling avg gap within each Name/Item group, then flags large gaps, and assigns a new group for each large gap or change in Name or Item.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Name,Item) %>%
  mutate(purch_num = row_number(),
         time_since_first = Date - first(Date),
         gap = Date - lag(Date, default = as.Date(-Inf)),
         avg_gap = time_since_first / (purch_num-1),
         new_grp_flag = gap > 180 | gap > 3*avg_gap) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(new_grp_flag))
```

Comment: It worked for me when I sorted by name, as my real data was messier. Thanks there's a lot in here for me to learn!